# Confusion on the helicity formalism

Tags: field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, helicity

I'm studying group representation theory from a more mathematical point of view but I don't understand the link between helicity formalism and the "classical one". They should be both constructed from the irreducible representations of Poincaré group.

Comment: One assumes you have carefully gone through the [basics](jacob and wick helicity formalism),  [and](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph218/Helicity_formalism.pdf), [and](https://cds.cern.ch/record/153636/files/cer-000064884.pdf)...  ?

Answer (score 0):

One-particle states are irreducible representations of the Poincar'e group. Fields are representations of the Lorentz group. To describe the dynamics of the theory, we must find a way to embed the dof of the state into fields.

The traditional way to deal with the 2 dof of a photon is to embed them in vector field $A_\mu$. One dof of $A_\mu$ is removed by equation of motion and the other is removed by gauge invariance and we are left with a total of $4-2=2$ dof.

The spinor-helicity formalism deals with the 2 dof of a photon by embedding them into a spinor. This completely removes the necessity of having gauge symmetry.

Comment: But in that formalism, also the states are different. I mean, it's like a different choice of the basis of the states, and it's difficult to find on which representations they belongs to.

Comment: p.s. My question doesn't deal with fields, al least in theory (cause I'm quite confuse).